# Wrapping custom type C++ pointer in Cython

Tags: python, c++, pointers, numpy, cython

What is the best way to wrap a custom type C++ pointer using Cython?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "A_c.h"
    cdef cppclass A:
       A();
       void Foo(A* vec);

cdef class pyA:
    cdef A *thisptr
    def ___cinit___(self):
        self.thisptr = new A()
    def __dealloc___(self):
        del self.thisptr
```

How should I use cython to wrap Foo? I have tried the following but I have gotten assertion errors from Buffer.py or the error that A is not a base type of memoryview slice

```
def Foo(self, np.ndarray[A, mode='c'] vec)
def Foo(self, A[::1] vec)
```

Comment: Is `A* vec` a pointer to a single object or a vector of objects of type `A`? I'm wondering because of the name "vec" and your use of numpy/memory views.

Comment: In this case, it is a pointer to a single object A, it is unfortunate that vec is chosen to be the placeholder name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically every time you want to pass an object of type `A` or a pointer to it you should use a Python object of type `pyA` - which is actually very similar to a pointer apart from the fact that it has reference counting, so it is like a [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in C++11, just that it only knows about references in Python (or Cython). [Edit] Note that Python objects can be `None`, you can easily prevent this using the `not None` clause.

Of course this is not only true for parameters but also for return types, so  every method that returns a pointer to an object of type `A` should return a `pyA`-object instead. For doing this you can create a `cdef` method name for example `setThis` that allows to set the pointer that is contained.

As mentioned already above, memory management is done in Python if you wrap pointers this way so on the one hand you need to ensure that if your C++ objects holds a pointer to an object that the Python object is not deleted (e.g. by storing a reference to the Python object in Cython) and on the other hand you should not delete objects from C++ if they are still contained in a Python object. You could also add flags to your Cython objects if the C++ object shall be deleted or not if you already have some kind of memory management in C++.

I've extended your example a bit in order to illustrate how this can be implemented in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "A_c.h":
    cdef cppclass A:
        A()
        void Foo(A* vec)
        A* Bar()

    cdef cppclass AContainer:
        AContainer(A* element)

cdef class pyA:
    cdef A *thisptr
    def ___cinit___(self):
        self.thisptr = new A()

    def __dealloc___(self):
        del self.thisptr

    cdef setThis(self, A* other):
        del self.thisptr
        self.thisptr = other
        return self

    def Foo(self, pyA vec not None): # Prevent passing None
        self.thisptr.Foo(vec.thisptr)

    def Bar(self):
        return pyA().setThis(self.thisptr.Bar())

cdef class pyAContainer:
    cdef AContainer *thisptr
    cdef pyA element

    def __cinit__(self, pyA element not None):
        self.element = element # store reference in order to prevent deletion
        self.thisptr = new AContainer(element.thisptr)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr # this should not delete the element
        # reference counting for the element is done automatically
```