# How wrap C function that takes a void* pointer?

Tags: python, c, dll, cython

I'm trying to wrap some functions defined in a DLL using Cython, the difficulty is that lots of this functions use pointers to void*, here is an example of functions prototype:

```
---------------"header.h"-----------------------

typedef void* HANDLE

int open(HANDLE* a_handle_pointer , int open_mode)

int use(HANDLE a_handle, int usage_mode )
```

the usage example in C is:

```
---------------"main.c" -----------------

#include"header.h"

HANDLE my_handle ;
int results ;
if(open(&my_handle ,1) == 0) /* open a handle with mode 1 */
{
    printf ("failed to open \n);
    return 0;
}

else printf("open success \n");

use(handle , 2); /* use handle (opened with open) in mode 2 */
```

As you can remark, the "Use" function can't do something unless the Handle had already been opened using the "open" function, which makes it confusing in Python/cython

Here is how I define my function "open" in Cython (one of several trials)

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
cdef extern from "header.h":
     ctypedef void*     HANDLE 
     int open(HANDLE* a_handle_pointer , int open_mode)


def Open( uintptr_t a_handle_pointer , int open_mode)

    return open(<HANDLE*> a_handle_pointer , open_mode)
```

I have tried to cast void * pointer to uintptr_t as some people advise, but still get the error:

```
" TypeError: an integer is required " when calling the function.

>>>from my_module import open
>>>open (handle , 1)
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

I am wondering how would I call a function from Python with an argument of type `void*` or `void**`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `return open(<HANDLE> a_handle_pointer , open_mode)`

Answer (score 1):

Writing the module/binding in Python itself is a *bad* idea, specially if pointers are involved. You should rather do it in C with something like this... **Warning**: This is specific to CPython 3+. CPython 2 extensions are coded differently! **BTW**: Renamed your `open` function as `load` because it conflicts with POSIX's [`open(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open).

```
// my_module.c: My Python extension!

/* Get us the CPython headers.
 */
#include "Python.h"

/* And your function's headers, of course.
 */
#include "header.h"

/* Actual structures used to store
 * a 'my_module.Handle' internally.
 */
typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD /* The base of all PyObjects. */
    HANDLE handle; /* Our handle, great! */
} my_module_HandleObject;

/* The type 'my_module.Handle'. This variable contains
 * a lot of strange, zero, and NULLified fields. Their
 * purpose and story is too obscure for SO, so better
 * off look at the docs for more details.
 */
static PyTypeObject my_module_HandleType =
{
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "my_module.Handle", /* Of course, this is the type's name. */
    sizeof(my_module_HandleObject), /* An object's size. */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, /* ... Don't ask. */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT, /* The type's flags. There's nothing special about ours, so use the defaults. */
    NULL /* No docstrings for you! */
};

/* The "wrapper" function. It takes a tuple of
 * CPython PyObject's and returns a PyObject.
 */
static PyObject *my_module_load(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int load_mode;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &load_mode) != 0) { /* Parse the argument list. It should have one single integer ("i") parameter. */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Create a Handle object, so as to put
     * in itthe handle we're about to get.
     */
    my_module_HandleObject *the_object = PyObject_New(my_module_HandleObject, &my_module_HandleType);
    if(the_object == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Finally, do our stuff.
     */
    if(load(&the_object->handle, load_mode) == -1) {
        Py_DECREF(the_object);
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(NULL);
        return NULL;
    }

    return (PyObject*)the_object;
}

/* The method table. It is a list of structures, each
 * describing a method of our module.
 */
static struct PyMethodDef my_module_functions[] =
{
    {
        "load", /* The method's name, as seen from Python code. */
        (PyCFunction)my_module_load, /* The method itself. */
        METH_VARARGS, /* This means the method takes arguments. */
        NULL, /* We don't have documentation for this, do we? */
    }, { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL } /* End of the list. */
};

/* Used to describe the module itself. */
static struct PyModuleDef my_module =
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "my_module", /* The module's name. */
    NULL, /* No docstring. */
    -1,
    my_module_functions,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

/* This function _must_ be named this way
 * in order for the module to be named as
 * 'my_module'. This function is sort of
 * the initialization routine for the module.
 */
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_my_module()
{
    my_module_HandleType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew; /* AFAIK, this is the type's constructor. Use the default. */
    if(PyType_Ready(&my_module_HandleType) < 0) { // Uh, oh. Something went wrong!
        return NULL;
    }

    PyObject *this_module = PyModule_Create(&my_module); /* Export the whole module. */
    if(this_module == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_INCREF(&my_module_HandleType);
    PyModule_AddObject(this_module, "Handle", (PyObject*)&my_module_HandleType);

    return this_module;
}
```

In order to build and install the extension, [see the docs on `distutils`](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html#building).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,I've been studying it for a while now ,so your Idea is to abandon Cython and focus on creating an extension module , so you defined the `Handle` type inside a struct , and the `load` function which will use access to the address of `the_object->handle`, and return `the_object` to be used in the future by the `use` function ,  It's a great idea I will work on it  , the typical usage will be now: `handle = load(2) ### use(handle, 1) ` , I have one question still : can the speed of this extension matche the speed of C (as it is written in C ) ?.

Comment: @werberbang: It *matches* the speed, performance, etc... of C, I mean, it's C after all. The only overhead is that of handling Python wrapper stuff. However, the cost of that is negligible. I wouldn't go with Cython, mainly because CPython extensions are more widely supported, and because Cython can be pretty limiting when working with pointers.

Comment: @werberbang: BTW, it's worth nothing that Cython is just a wrapper language around C extensions.

Comment: Why to do this and not define a class using Cython? They can contain HANDLE like pointers.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala: Of course that's possible (note: I have a negative bias towards Cython). However, this solution is (a bit) more flexible, and has the benefits of C-land performance, which the OP seems to be seeking for (see his comment above). [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5729449/5249858) for details.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala is there an online tutorial for making that , the difficulty that i'm facing here is the 1: "cannot convert python object to HANDLE or HANDLE*" when I compile the pyx file . and 2: I dont know how would I pass an argument of  type`void* or void** `from within python to my function or get one from it  : ex `int open(HANDLE* a_handle_pointer , int open_mode) `.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your pointer in a Cython/Python object and then pass an instance of that object to the Python versions of your open and use functions. Please look at the question [Wrapping custom type C++ pointer in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770963/wrapping-custom-type-c-pointer-in-cython) for how to wrap and pass around pointers in Cython. The answer I provided there should also work for `void`-pointers.

Unless you really want to map the C-API as unmodified as possible to Python you should also consider using a different, possibly object-oriented design for the Python interface. For example you could put the call to `open()` in the constructor of your Python class that wraps the `HANDLE` pointer, raise an exception on errors and make `use()` an instance method of of that class. That way you can prevent errors from using unitialized pointers and integer return values for indicating errors which might be unexpected for a Python programmer.